# Can I access Companion Object properties in the Companion Class using Scala

Tags: scala

I have the following very simple code...

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.{LogManager, Logger}

class TestSingle {
  def doSomething(): Unit = logger.debug("My Log Statement")
}
object TestSingle {
  private val logger: Logger = LogManager.getLogger(classOf[TestSingle])
}
```

But it won't let me access logger from the companion class. Do I need to move the logger to the class and add the final keyword or is there something else I am missing about how to do this?

Comment: Yes you can access them, but you need to use its fully qualified name. e.g. `TestSingle.logger` or if you have many properties that you want to access you can add a `import TestSingle._` at the beginning of the class _(be careful with all it imports)_

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. Either qualify the name when you use it:

```
def doSomething(): Unit = TestSingle.logger.debug("My Log Statement")
```

or import everything from the companion object to bring `logger` in scope:

```
class TestSingle {
  import TestSingle._

  def doSomething(): Unit = logger.debug("My Log Statement")
}
```

Comment: thanks forgot the import thing that makes sense

Comment: What about if I want to access a class variable in the object?

Comment: The same way that you access a `val` like `logger`. But if you are going to have mutable state I recommend using methods to update it rather than writing `var` directly from outside the `object`.